# Flot remove dataseries

Tags: flot

This is how I remove data points upon clicking a datapoint:

```
item.series.data[item.dataIndex].shift()
item.series.data[item.dataIndex].shift()
```

Whats the code to delete the entire series that the data point belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are doing this from a `plotclick` handler:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item){
        var someData = plot.getData(); //get the series array
        someData.splice(item.seriesIndex,1); //remove the index of the one clicked
        plot.setData(someData); //set the data
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();  //redraw
    }        
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X2q69/).

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X2q69/1/) which deletes from multiple graphs based on **series name** instead of index position.

```
$(".chart").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item){
        var label = item.series.label;
        $([plot1, plot2]).each(function(i,plotObj){
            var someData = plotObj.getData();
            for (var i=0; i<someData.length; i++){
                if (someData[i].label == label){
                    someData.splice(i,1);
                }                
            }
            plotObj.setData(someData);
            plotObj.setupGrid();
            plotObj.draw();                
        });
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot mark. Can I ask you one more question. If I had 2 plots on same page, is it possible to delete the same series on both plots. If I clicked on 'series A' in plotA that series would get deleted and also the same series 'series A' would get deleted in plot2 and vice versa....Thanks alot for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @user3121522, see updates to answer.  I modified it to delete from multiple graphs based on a click in either one.  It also will delete by series label instead of index position.